# Absolute continuity of measure and $\epsilon-\delta$ condtion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

I am reading Folland's `Real Analysis` p. 89

Theorem:

> Let $\nu$ be a finite signed measure and $\mu$ a positive measure on $(X,M) $. Then $\nu << \mu$ iff for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such tant $|\nu(E)|<\epsilon$ whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$.

In the proof, it says that "clearly" the $\epsilon-\delta$ condition implies that $\nu << \mu$.

I have trouble on seeing why this holds.
How does this imply $\mu(E) = 0 \Rightarrow \nu(E) = 0 $ with $E\in M$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu(E)=0$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have $|\nu(E)|<\varepsilon$. So then $|\nu(E)|=...$